# DeAuth not DeAuthing Client (Aireplay-ng)

Tags: aircrack-ng

I'm trying to perform a De-authentication attack on my own network and client. However, the client *never* disconnects and I cannot boot the client from the AP.

I'm running:

```
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX wlan0 -c XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

- I'm close to the client
- Target is a basic Apple Macbook computer
- AP is an ARRIS (I've been able to capture handshakes easily from this AP)
- I've sent endless deauth packets for 5+ minutes, client refuses to disconnect.

Further, when deauthing the AP only, the AP is still fully visible in a WiFi list for others to connect to.

Something I'm missing?

Comment: you could maybe give some other tools a try like https://github.com/aircrack-ng/mdk4 or even the mdk3 version and see if you get any different results. Might help you limit the scope of where the issue is as this is a very broad question.

Comment: I ran an mdk4 attack directly to the client, still can’t take it down.

I’ve tried a few routers now. I’m trying another NIC later but I do see the deauth packets in the air yet the AP won’t go down. I did read somewhere that even if you still see the client “connected” the connection is actually deauth, but that’s not the case. Client still has full internet access.